# Stored procedure not working for inserting data

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, procedure

I have this table:

```
User

user_id int PK
username varchar(20)
secret_code varchar(20)
name varchar(20)
age int
gender varchar(20)
city varchar(20)
latest_signin_time timestamp
latest_signout_time timestamp
loc_list json
buddy_list json
```

I created a stored procedure:

```
create procedure insert_users(IN user_id int , in username varchar(20),in secret_code varchar(20), 
                   in name varchar(20), in age int, in gender varchar(20), in city varchar(20), 
                   in latest_signin_time timestamp, in latest_signout_time timestamp, 
                   in loc_list json , in buddy_list json)
begin

insert into user values(user_id, username, secret_code, name, age, gender, city, 
                        latest_signin_time, latest_signout_time, loc_list,buddy_list)
end ;


call insert_user(​'1', 'avs431','pwd1','Ameya','22','Male','Mumbai',null,null,'[]','[]'​​);
```

However, my code isn't running and I keep getting "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'end' at line 9"

I'm not sure what is going wrong here. Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Comment: You forget `;` after INSERT statement, before `END;`. PS. For single-statement procedure BEGIN-END block is excess.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
create procedure insert_users(IN user_id int , in username varchar(20),in secret_code varchar(20), 
                   in name varchar(20), in age int, in gender varchar(20), in city varchar(20), 
                   in latest_signin_time timestamp, in latest_signout_time timestamp, 
                   in loc_list json , in buddy_list json)
/* begin */

insert into user values(user_id, username, secret_code, name, age, gender, city, 
                        latest_signin_time, latest_signout_time, loc_list,buddy_list)
/* end */ ;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I keep getting errors for procedures, like for this table: Buddies(first_user_id int, second_user_id int, time timestamp, status varchar(10)), I created this procedure, create procedure friend_requests(in first_user_id int, in second_user_id int, in time timestamp, 
        in status varchar(10)) I keep getting error

Answer (score 0):

The commands in procedure terminate with semicolon (`;`). Use prefixes in the procedure parameters so the parameters won't be mixed up with column names. Also, list the column names in `INSERT` so your procedure will work even if a column is added to the table.

```
delimiter //
create procedure insert_users(
in_user_id int, 
in_username varchar(20),
in_secret_code varchar(20), 
in_name varchar(20), 
in_age int, 
in_gender varchar(20), 
in_city varchar(20), 
in_latest_signin_time timestamp, 
in_latest_signout_time timestamp, 
in_loc_list json, 
in_buddy_list json
)
begin

insert into user (user_id, username, secret_code, name, age, gender, 
       city, latest_signtime, latest_signout_time, loc_list, buddy_list)
values(in_user_id, in_username, in_secret_code, in_name, in_age, in_gender, 
       in_city, in_latest_signin_time, in_latest_signout_time, in_loc_list, in_buddy_list);

end
//
delimiter ;

call insert_user(​'1', 'avs431','pwd1','Ameya','22','Male','Mumbai',null,null,'[]','[]'​​);
```